# Separately loading data into two Core Data entities with relationships using Swift

Tags: swift, core-data, relationship

I'm loading data into two Core Data entities on app start up. No problem loading the normal attributes, but I can't figure out how to set the relationships in Swift 5.

Of the two relevant entities, CellData has a single 'to one' relationship with Selector (each Selector row can have many CellData rows).

[image]

My single model class loads the data for two entities...

```
class LoadData
{
init ()
{
```

using a for loop, which firstly defines Selector entity data for a picker...

```
    for count in 0...3
    {
        var text = "Value not found"
...

        switch count
        {
        case 0:
            text = "Masculine"
        case 1:
            text = "Neutral"
        case 2:
            text = "Feminine"
        case 3:
            text = "Plural"
        default:
            text = "Value unassigned"
        }
```

... and then calls a method (below) to add data to the entity "Selector".

```
        loadSelector(text: text, sortOrder: sortOrder, ...)
    }
```

... Within the same init, there is a second for loop to define CellData

```
    for count in 0...51
    {
        var text = "Cell text not found"
        var sortOrder: Int32 = 0
        ...

        sortOrder = Int32(count)
        ...
        switch count
        {
        case 0:
            text = "Blank"
            color1 = subject
            colorRangeLoc1 = 0
            colorRangeLen1 = Int32(text.count)
        ...   
        case 8:
            text = "Der Mann"
            color1 = article
            ...

        case 9:
            text = "Die Frau"
            color1 = article
            color2 = subject
            colorRangeLoc1 = 0
            colorRangeLoc2 = 4
            colorRangeLen1 = 3
            colorRangeLen2 = 4
            underlineRangeLoc1 = 1
            underlineRangeLen1 = 2
        ...
```

... which also passes the data from each loop into a load method.

```
           loadCellData(text: text, ...)
    }
}

func loadSelector(text: String, sortOrder: Int32, color1: String?, color2: String?, color3: String?, colorRangeLoc1: Int32?, colorRangeLen1: Int32?, colorRangeLoc2: Int32?, colorRangeLen2: Int32?, colorRangeLoc3: Int32?, colorRangeLen3: Int32?)
{
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext

    let entry: Selector = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Selector", into: context) as! Selector

    entry.text = text
    entry.sortOrder = sortOrder

    do { try context.save() }
    catch let error as NSError
    { print("Could not save. \(error), \(error.userInfo)") }
}
```

This is probably not the best approach, but I'm working towards loading the data via a plist.

What I can't figure out, is how to create the relationship in CellData. Case 8, for example, needs a relationship to the Selector data where .text = 'Masculine', and CellData, case 9, should be related to the Selector entry .text = 'Feminine'.

Am I supposed to re-fetch the Selector entries - before or within - the second for loop then assign within each case? I've tried this, but had no success - if possible please show code, and where the code needs to be. Most information seems to be in Obj-c. Swift 5 would be awesome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I found to define the relationship to an existing record is to fetch the record individually from CoreData.

Taken from Hacking Swift Project 38, where 'commit' is an instantiated CoreData Entity with a relationship to Author entity:

```
var commitAuthor: Author!       // instantiate an Author object

let authorRequest = Author.createFetchRequest()     // create a fetch request...
authorRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "name == %@", json["commit"]["committer"]["name"].stringValue)       // predicating the author's name...

let authors = container.viewContext.fetch(authorRequest)

commitAuthor = authors[0] }   // pull the author out of the array
// and assign the author to the commit.author relationship
commit.author = commitAuthor
```

While the question was more about assigning the relationship, the following (based on Joachim's answer) is a better way to load the data in a way that is visible and transferrable to a plist or JSON upload. Basically, to loop through an array of dictionaries:

```
let genders: NSArray = [["text": "Masculine", "sortOrder" : Int32(0)], ["text": "Neutral", "sortOrder" : Int32(1)], ["text": "Feminine", "sortOrder" : Int32(2)], ["text": "Plural", "sortOrder" : Int32(3)]]

    // loading a gender entity in context with a dictionary of items from array
    for eachDicItem in genders
    {
        let gender = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Gender",
                                                in: context)!
        let genderInContext = Gender(entity: gender,
                            insertInto: context)

        let genderDictionary = eachDicItem as! [String : Any]

        genderInContext.text = genderDictionary["text"] as? String
        genderInContext.sortOrder = genderDictionary["sortOrder"] as? Int32 ?? 99
    }

    // save the context
    do { try context.save() }
    catch let error as NSError
    { print("Could not save. \(error), \(error.userInfo)") }
```

Answer (score 0):

Treat them much like ordinary objects, Core Data handles much of the magic stuff for you.

I would create a method that creates all selector and returns them as a dictionary with name as key (or any other collections that suits you)

```
func createSelectors(text: String) -> [String: Select] {
    var result = [String: Selector]() 
    //loop creating Selector 
    result[text: entity]
    return result
}
```

you can even skip your loadSelector method and do the actual instantiation as

```
let entity = Selector(context: context)
```

in the createSelectors method and `try context.save()` can be done at the end, not for every object. Note that adding the creating the object like this puts it in the NSManagedObjectContext and that is enough for now to be able to use the objects, saving can actually be done once at the very end of your loading.

Now when creating CellData you can do something like

```
let selectors = createSelectors()
...
let cellData = CellData(context: context)
if let sel = selectors {
    cellData.selectorToData = sel
}
....
```

and once all CellData entities has been created you can call `try context.save()`

`context` in all code above is the managed object you get this way, `let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext, but you probably got that already.

"Selector" is such a special name in Swift since it is a built in structs I would seriously consider changing the name of this entity.

Comment: I'll certainly try to adopt this approach. To confirm: let selectors = createSelectors() will return a dictionary that has also been put into the let entity = Selector(context: context), and saved into Core Data. My Selectors entity, however, has several attributes, not just text, and I'm not sure how to handle this - what to return at least. And secondly, I don't see where a specific entry in cellData, say with .text = "Der Mann" is linked via the .dataToSelector relationship to the specific entry in Selector with .text = "Masculine". (good point about "Selector", will refactor as "Gender")

Comment: For your Selector (Gender) entity you should set all attributes as you do today in loadSelector, make them complete with everything set in createSelectors (if I understood your question correctly). For the second part I assume you can’t automate this but need to hardcode which selector to use for each CellData instance

Comment: yes, each CellData instance just is a Gender. There is nothing about the CellData text to know it is a Gender, although the sequence, as data is entered, does match Gender values - first 20 or so, relationship to "Masculine", etc.

Comment: I unfortunately can't understand some things 1) What text value is passed into the createGender / createSelector? 2) For var result = [String : Selector], is String the name of the attribute, and Selector is the value? 3) Where is NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject? 4) Instead of result[text: entity], do you mean result = [text : entity], and if so, is text the passed in value or the name of the attribute; and is entity the value for Core Data? I've read the Apple doc.s, and seen their videos - if you've a better source, please let me know.